# Python find/extract keyword from list inside loop

Tags: python, numpy, find

I am trying to extract specific keyword from a list but for some reason I get  [] empty box or python spits out the whole list which is not what I want. This is the code I have right now.

```
appendxxxx12 = list(appendxxxx12)
value0 = list(value0)
matching = ([s for s in appendxxxx12 if value0 in s])
print matching
```

How appendxxxx12 looks inside:

```
 1. [array([[ '-0.00043%,2/28/2017 19:00:00 OT,0.18628309032095,1,1',
        'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Newyork.csv'],
       [ '-0.000040%,2/28/2017 23:00:00 OT,0.0348181598043078,1,1',
        'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Alaska.csv'],
       [ '-0.00000007%,2/28/2017 1:00:00 PM,0.15740445010141,1,1',
        'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Canada.csv'],
```

How value0 looks inside:

```
[382, 'Newyork.csv']
[446, 'Alaska.csv']
[491, 'Canada.csv']
```

Where I need help is taking whatever the value0 is and find it inside appendxxx12 and printing it as output:

```
for example 

    print answer
    output = [382, 'Newyork.csv'] , [[ '-0.00043%,2/28/2017 19:00:00 OT,0.18628309032095,1,1',C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Newyork.csv']
```

Comment: It seems as though your appendxxx12 is messed up. Do you really need to have: a LIST containing an ARRAY containing a LIST containing LISTS of two STRINGS? Could you reduce appendxxx12 to just a LIST of LISTS?

Comment: Is value0 list of lists?

Comment: Why did you tag `numpy`?  Are these lists initially numpy arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using list comprehension,

```
yourlist = [['-0.00043%,2/28/2017 19:00:00 OT,0.18628309032095,1,1',
         'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Newyork.csv'],
        ['-0.000040%,2/28/2017 23:00:00 OT,0.0348181598043078,1,1',
         'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Alaska.csv'],
        ['-0.00000007%,2/28/2017 1:00:00 PM,0.15740445010141,1,1',
         'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Canada.csv']]
value0 = [[382, 'Newyork.csv'],
      [446, 'Alaska.csv'],
      [491, 'Canada.csv']]


for nval in [(x,y) for x in value0 for y in yourlist if x[1] in y[1]]:
       print nval[:2]
```

Comment: I used ur code, however I needed to make adjustments to appendxxxx12. turning it into numpy.array first with a reshape of (-1,2) than it finally worked.

Answer (score 3):

If I don't misunderstand your question, you can try :

```
yourlist = [['-0.00043%,2/28/2017 19:00:00 OT,0.18628309032095,1,1',
             'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Newyork.csv'],
            ['-0.000040%,2/28/2017 23:00:00 OT,0.0348181598043078,1,1',
             'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Alaska.csv'],
            ['-0.00000007%,2/28/2017 1:00:00 PM,0.15740445010141,1,1',
             'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Canada.csv']]

value0 = [[382, 'Newyork.csv'],
          [446, 'Alaska.csv'],
          [491, 'Canada.csv']]

for value in value0:
    for list in yourlist:
        for l in list:
            if value[1] in l:
                print value, list
```

Output:

```
[382, 'Newyork.csv'] ['-0.00043%,2/28/2017 19:00:00 OT,0.18628309032095,1,1', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Newyork.csv']
[446, 'Alaska.csv'] ['-0.000040%,2/28/2017 23:00:00 OT,0.0348181598043078,1,1', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Alaska.csv']
[491, 'Canada.csv'] ['-0.00000007%,2/28/2017 1:00:00 PM,0.15740445010141,1,1', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\A\\\\Desktop\\\\Time\\\\Canada.csv']
```

Comment: I get an error : TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I think the only time you're using `getItem` in that code is `value[1]`, so I'd assume your `value0` list isn't the same as stated above and some `value` is getting assigned as an integer instead of a list.